Steps on solving point to plane exercises
I just want confirmation that the steps I've took to solve these two exercises are correct
Exercise 1
Consider in R3 the line $l$ defined by:

\begin{cases}
x = 2 + 3t \\
y = 2 - 2t \\
z = 1 + t \\
t \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
and the points $A = (1, 4, -1)$ and $B = (1, 3, 4)$.
Let $\pi$ be the plane that contains the line $l$ and the point $A$. Calculate the distance between point $B$ and the plane $\pi$.
Exercise 2
Consider in R3 the line $l$, the plane $\pi$, and the point $A$, where $l$ is given by:
$
l = \begin{cases}
x = -1 - 2t \\
y = 3 + 3t \\
z = 4 + 2t
\end{cases}
$
$\pi : -x + 2y - z = 8$
and $A = (4, 2, 6)$.
Let $\pi_1$ be the plane that contains $l$ and is perpendicular to $\pi$. Find the distance between the point $A$ and the plane $\pi_1$.
What I did for exercise 1:

Got the direction vector of $l$: $d = (3, -2, 1)$
Got a point on the line. When $t = 0$, then $P0 = (2,2,1)$
The normal vector of plane $\pi$ can be found using the cross product of two vectors in the plane, $d \times v$
Need vector $v$ and I assumed goes from $P0$ to $A$ (not sure if from $A$ to $P0$ or from $P0$ to $A$). So, $v = P0-A$. $v = (-1,2,-2)$
Cross product of normal vector $n = (2,5,4)$
Equation of plane is given by normal vector passing through point $P0$: $2x+5y+4z - 18 =0$
Distance from the plane $\pi$ to point $B$ is: $\sqrt{5}$

What I did for exercise 2:

Got the direction vector of $l$: $d = (-2, 3, 2)$
Got a point on the line. When $t = 0$, then $P0 = (-1,3,4)$
The normal vector of plane $\pi$ can be found using the coefficients of the equation: $n = (-1, 2, -1)$
Since $\pi_1$ is perpendicular to $\pi$, then normal vector of $\pi_1$ is parallel to the normal vector of $\pi$. So, I make the cross product of $n \times d$: $n1 = (7, 4, 1)$
I got the equation of plane $\pi_1$ by using $n1$ and $P0$: $7x+4y+z - 9 = 0$
Distance from the plane $\pi$ to point $A$ is: $\dfrac{\sqrt{66}}{2}$

I was able to solve these by looking at the notes of my professor but I didn't really understand for instance why in the cross product of

First exercise: $d \times v$
Second exercise: $n \times d$

